# Wrong scale when exporting Google Earth Engine image as NumPy array

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, google-earth-engine-python-api, digital-image-processing

Relatively new to EE. I am trying to export a Google Earth image to a numpy array to run further processing. I have managed to convert the image to an array and have plotted it, but my plotted figure is too dark and also too pixelated.

My intended output should look something like this:

[image]

, where I am able to make out apartments/ roads.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ee
import geemap

# define region of interest
coords=[103.7298,1.49716,
        103.730728,1.46695
        ]

EXPORT_REGION=ee.Geometry.Rectangle(coords)

L8SR = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1')

collection=(L8SR.filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-04-30').
            filterBounds(EXPORT_REGION)
            )
# remove clouds
image = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite(collection, percentile=50)

test_image=image.reproject(crs=ee.Projection('EPSG:3995'), scale=10)

# export ee image to numpy array
img_np=geemap.ee_to_numpy(test_image, ['B4','B3','B2'], EXPORT_REGION)

# plot image
rgb_img_test = img_np[:, :, 0:3].astype('uint8')

plt.imshow(rgb_img_test)
plt.show()
```

and this is my output

[image]

Not too sure why my image is so dark and more importantly, why the image is at such low resolution despite the scale parameter being set at 10 (my understanding is that this corresponds to the scale bar we see on Google Earth).

Comment: Landsat imagery isn't 10m to begin with, it's 30m (for most bands) https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I tried 30m too and the output is identical to the one where I set scale to 10m. On this note, do also let me know if you have a different approach to visualise the output image.  Could it be the case that the error lies with my visualisation method, and not the scale parameter? Thanks!